# React hook has an unnecessary dependency

Tags: reactjs

hello i'm getting this :

> React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'product.selectedFilesVideos'. Either exclude it or remove the
> dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

my state:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({
     .......
    selectedFilesVideos: [],
     .......
  });
```

my function :

```
  const addSelectedFilesVideos = useCallback(
    (files) => {
      setProduct((prevProduct) => {
        return { ...prevProduct, selectedFilesVideos: files };
      });
    },
    [product.selectedFilesVideos]
  );
```

where i use it :

```
<FileManger
  addSelectedFiles={addSelectedFilesVideos}
  selectFiles={product.selectedFilesVideos}
  acceptFormat="video/*"
  videoOrPics="Drop video files here or click to upload."
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the warning by removing `product.selectedFilesVideos` from the dependency array of the 'useCallback'. Since there is no actual dependency in this array for the callback hook, it should still work as expected and it will fix your warning.

```
 const addSelectedFilesVideos = useCallback(
    (files) => {
      setProduct((prevProduct) => {
        return { ...prevProduct, selectedFilesVideos: files };
      });
    },
    []
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass to dependency array `product.selectedFilesVideos` which is not used in the function of `useCallback`. This array is used to call `useCallback` and update function when one of the dependency was updated.

That's why there is the React warning.

For more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: i have update my question can you look now?  i mean product.selectedFilesVideos is beign updated, because it is inside product state.